# Lock/CriticalSection vs volatile in c++ for visibility

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I have a map which can be updated by multiple thread. And a critical section that guards the read/writes to the map.

```
CCriticalSection mapCS;
map<string, string> mFileNameToInstance;
```

I use single lock everytime I access the map.

```
CSingleLock lock(&mapCS);  
lock.Lock();
// perform whatever reads/write with the map.
mFileNameToInstance.insert("a", "b");
lock.Unlock();
```

My question is,

- is it sufficient to guarantee the visibility of mFileNameToInstance to all other threads or does it need to be volatile ?

Comment: If you have C++11 available, just go for `<thread>`

Comment: you want to use volatile keyword to help compiler to sort out what you can or can't use in multithreaded env ? http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/volatile-the-multithreaded-programmers-b/184403766

Comment: It is sufficient, the lock includes a memory barrier.

Comment: Ok. In that case, do we need to sync up read also with the lock?

Comment: I mean, I have a variable which can have multiple writers and all the writers are synced with lock. But the readers are accessed as is without locks. In that case, is it guarenteed to have any writers' change reflected in the reader ? Its just a simple int

Comment: The readers also need the lock. In the course of one writer performing its operation there can be intermediate states, before all parts of the operation are complete. Reading at that moment could produce invalid data.

Comment: @philippelhardy, that article is crack-addled. [`volatile` is almost useless for MT programming](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming). Do not use `volatile` with threads, even on Windows where the compiler gives it special meaning, people will laugh and call you names.

Comment: @JonathanWakely this is a use of volatile indeed. Even mentioned in wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable Compile-time detection of race conditions. i think Andrei Alexandrescu (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrei_Alexandrescu) the writer would be better than me to argue if it is crack-addled.

Comment: @MohanKumar Of course i now you were not asking about THAT (this of my previous comment) use of volatile keyword. In your question you should add that you want the readers to access information without lock, i would then answer : use lock for readers too.

Comment: @philippelhardy, I know who Andrei is, that doesn't change the fact this is pure crap: _"[`volatile`]'s intended to be used in conjunction with variables that are accessed and modified in different threads."_ A more recent, more useful  Dr Dobbs article is [volatile vs volatile](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/volatile-vs-volatile/212701484)

Comment: @JonathanWakely i am from those who follow people who knows their field and you are one of them. When i saw this article i was just very surprised to see this kind of use of volatile. And i didn't see this usage anywhere else. You tell is crap, so i won't use it. My only point is if people who knows ( i of course put Andrei Alexandrescu in this group too ) disagree , they have to made there mind together and i take the winner advice; if one can be found :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always access the map (both reading and writing) then you don't been to flag anything as volatile as the lock will but up a memory barrier so that any changes are visible to all threads.

However, flagging the map as `volatile` probably won't work. According the the [MSDN documentation for volatile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd.aspx) the keyword has no effect that exceeds then maximum size that can be copied on the current architecture by using one instruction. The `map` class will undoubtably fall under this condition.

Also, don't use a locking mechanism that requires you to call some unlock function. Your `CSingleLock` should do the unlocking in its destructor using the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) pattern.

Comment: Thanks. It prompted me another question  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22668250/object-level-csinglelock-vs-method-level-csinglelock

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to declare the map `volatile` the `CCriticalSection` handles all the concurrency blocking requirements you need.

Comment: `InterlockedExchange` is a full memory barrier, what is the benefit of using `volatile` with it?

Comment: @JonathanWakely:  `InterlockedExchange` requires `volatile`, so I guess the benefit would be to compile without warnings. :-)

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy, not according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683590(v=vs.85).aspx), have you confused "can accept" with "requires"?

Comment: To be honest I haven't tried pushing the 'volatile' implied requirement of the Interlocked synchronization functions because as we all know it's VERY hard to test. If volatile prevents the compiler aggressively optimizing access to the variable and the Interlocked functions show 'volatile' in the signature then I'll use volatile.

Comment: Can anyone of you compile a final answer ? So I get that we don't need volatile with CCriticalSection.

Comment: You absolutely DO NOT NEED volatile when using a CCriticalSection. No one's contesting that, we're just discussing whether you need it for the Interlocked series of functions.