# Object level CSingleLock vs method level CSingleLock

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, mfc, locking

I have a class which declares a `CCriticalSection` object. Lets say for simplicity that only one thread should enter and execute the methods of that class at a time.

My question here is,

Are there any differences in me declaring a class level `CSingleLock` and use it's Lock() and Unlock() method and me declaring CSingleLock object in each function.

```
class ExclusiveClass
{
    CCriticalSection mCS;
    CSingleLock      mSL;
    ExclusiveClass() : mCS(), mSL(&mCS) { }
    void someMethod 
    {
        mSL.Lock();
        // Do whatever you want
        mSL.Unlock();
    }
}
```

versus

```
class ExclusiveClass
{
    CCriticalSection mCS;
    ExclusiveClass() : mCS() {}
    void someMethod 
    {
        CSingleLock sl(&mCS);
        sl.Lock()
        // Do whatever you want
        sl.Unlock();
    }
}
```

I know one definitive difference. In second approach, we need not call the Unlock() method explicitly. Upon returning from a function, the `sl`'s destructor will be called and the method lock will unlock automatically.

My concern here is wrt exceptions. When an exception happens, I am for sure the second approach will unlock automatically. What about first approach ? And are there any other differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example isn't exception safe. If something throws an exception after the `Lock` but before the call to `Unlock` you'll never release the lock, which is bad!

For this sort of pattern you should use the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) approach that you show in your second example. Not only is it exception safe but it saves you having to worry about calling `Unlock`, which you could easily forget to do and get some difficult to track down errors.

Comment: Thanks. Are they the only difference ?